# Multi-purpose note-taking software

Tags: windows

I take a lot of short notes. For that [CintaNotes](http://cintanotes.com/) does the job. (The free version is adequate for the standard user.) I can create notebooks, tag each note, etc.

When I decide to write  book or an article, CintaNotes is not good; better to have a Markdown Editor, like [Joplin](https://joplinapp.org/) or [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/).

The problem is it is a pain to have notes in one app, and start copying them to another app (and some times I start taking notes to, say, Joplin, and forget to copy it to CintaNotes, etc.); all kinds of things that slow me down and work less efficient than it could be.

Is there an app which somehow nicely combines both modes?

Comment: Can you specify what both modes is? Short and long notes?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Notion](https://www.notion.so/).

You can create nested pages as well as a database of pages. The database can have many properties including tags (you can set any name you want).

It also supports markdown.

Answer (score 0):

For my use (which maybe is different from yours) I love using Google's Keep. Very simple, I use it on mobile, but synchronizes with the PC/web version, it is free and let's me dictate with a good ability in voice recognition.